# Show next database values on button click

Tags: php, html

I have made a quiz, but instead of showing all of the questions at once I want to show them 1 by 1. So question 1 is shown first and when the answer is submitted question 2 is shown etc. The questions and multiple choice answers are shown on the page from the database with sql statements. But I can't seem to manage it to show the questions after each other.The way the databasebase is setup is, there is a question with 4 options and a correct answer column. I want to show the question and the 4 options that go with that question. This is the code I use to show all the questions with the answers from the database, it would be nice if someone could help me with a way to show them one by one:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "kinderboekenweek");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      $i =0;
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo " Vraag: ". $row["vraag"].

         "<ul class = 'answers".$i."'.>
         </br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=".$row['optie1']." id='optie1".$i."'>  </br>".

         "</br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=". $row["optie2"]." id='optie2".$i."'> </br> ".

         "</br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=". $row["optie3"]." id='optie3".$i."'>  </br>".

         "</br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=". $row["optie4"]." id='optie4".$i."'>  </br>".

         "</br></br>
         </ul>";
         $i++;
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";

}
```

Comment: Use offset limit to hardcode your pagination

Comment: you should wrap those input buttons with a <form> html set I would think. Also - in your SELECT query you can limit which question you pull from the database. throw a <hidden> element into the form and identify which question is 'next' in the list - use the value from that hidden element to identify which question to pull from the database in the select query so each time a button is clicked - the hidden element passes a value to the page via POST and the select can use that value as a condition in the query.